# (B)^I notation in topology

Tags: general-topology, notation

Please can you explain me this notation (B)^I ,where B is basis of topology and I us interval and U belong to topology generated by B and Ui belong to (B)^I and U = union of Ui Thank you

Comment: Is it $(B)^I$ ? And $U_i$ ?. And $i\in I$ or $i\in\mathbb N$? Where is this comming from? You can you use basic Latex commands.

Comment: Yes from book Mathematiques Analyse cours complet avec 600 tests 'page 835

Comment: $B^I$ is the set of maps from $I$ to $B,$ i.e. the set of families $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ such that each $U_i$ is an element of $B.$ This notation is not specific to topology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: So is it solved? You are encouraged to post and accept [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). (I still do knot know what was meaning of the parenthesis in $(B)^I$.)

Comment: Imo no answer is needed: this question should be closed as a duplicate (for instance of the post linked above). This notation is not specific to topology. (Note however that in your case, the open sets of the topology generated by $B$ are the sets of the form $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i,$
where $(U_i)_{i\in I}\in B^I$.)